# Comparing strings in a 2D array to user input

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to get the user to choose a team (names are contained in 2D array), type the desired name/team, then use a for loop to compare the user's typed word with the words of a 2D array, and use that loop to access each string in the array:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    char cPlaychar[10][15] = { "BlackFurs", "EppiGods", "FairyDusters",  
                               "Dwarvin", "Bloods", "Cryptics", "ArcAngels",
                               "DarkVillians", "Heroiteks", "Mass", };
    char cKeyInput[15];
    int results[10];

    std::cout << "Please select a character
                  by typing the name and pressing enter" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> cKeyInput;

    for(int Array = 0; Array < 10; Array++){
       switch (Array){
       case '0': 
           results[0] = strcmp(cPlaychar[Array], cKeyInput);
           if (results[0] = 0){
               std::cout << "you have picked the first char";
           }
           break;
       case '1': results[1] = strcmp(cPlaychar[Array], cKeyInput);
           if (results[1] = 0){
               std::cout << "you have picked the secound char";
           }
           break;
       case '2':results[2] = strcmp(cPlaychar[Array], cKeyInput);
           if (results[2] = 0){
               std::cout << "you have picked the third char";
           }
           break;
       case '3':results[3] = strcmp(cPlaychar[Array], cKeyInput);
           if (results[3] = 0){
               std::cout << "you have picked the fourth char";
           }
           break;
       case '4':results[4] = strcmp(cPlaychar[Array], cKeyInput);
           if (results[4] = 0){
               std::cout << "you have picked the fith char";
           } 
           break;
       case '5':results[5] = strcmp(cPlaychar[Array], cKeyInput);
           if (results[5] = 0){
               std::cout << "you have picked the sixth char";
           }
           break;
       case '6':results[6] = strcmp(cPlaychar[Array], cKeyInput);
           if (results[6] = 0){
               std::cout << "you have picked the seventh char";
           }
           break;
       case '7':results[7] = strcmp(cPlaychar[Array], cKeyInput);
           if (results[7] = 0){
               std::cout << "you have picked the eighth char";
           }
           break;
       case '8':results[8] = strcmp(cPlaychar[Array], cKeyInput);
           if (results[8] = 0){
               std::cout << "you have picked the ninth char";
           }
           break;
       case '9':results[9] = strcmp(cPlaychar[Array], cKeyInput);
           if (results[9] = 0){
               std::cout << "you have picked the tenth char";
           }
           break;
       } // end of switch
} // end of for
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you please add a specific question regarding your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you can put

```
using namespace std ;
```

in the beginning and remove all (std::)

second in `if (results[ ] = 0)` this must be `if (results[ ] == 0)`

third i don't know why you use this method , you can do it easily like this

```
string names[] = {"a","b"} ;
string num[]   = { "first", "second" } ;

string input;
cin >> input;

for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
  if (input == names[i])
    cout << "you choose" << num[i] << endl;
}
```

but if you want 2d array you can do this

```
char names[2][2] = { "a", "b" };
char num[2][7]   = { "first", "second" };

char input[2];
cin >> input ;

for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
  if (!strcmp(input,names[i]))
    cout << "you choose " << num[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Replacing `std::` with `using namespace std` is considered as bad practice since it may cause problems with conflicting names of functions when you use multiple namespaces.